# Signature Validation for a SAML Authn Request via GET method fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml, saml-2.0, sign

## I am sending a *SIGNED* authnRequest to the idp using c# and asp.net. My code signs the authnRequest but the signature validation fails at idp.

## Details

I tried a lot of solutions but in vain. 
This is what i am doing following guidlines set by https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf:

- STEPS

  1. Deflate the auth request, then base64 encode it and finally Url Encode it. Lets call it AR
  2. Url encode the RelayState. Lets call it RS
  3. Url encode the signing Algorithm string. Lets call it SA
  4. So the string to be signed now becomes
     *SAMLRequest=AR&RelayState=RS&SigAlg=SA*
  5. Now i sign the string we get in step #4 using our private key (service provider private key).
     6.The resultant signature that i get, i base 64 encode it, and then URL encode it. Thus i get a base64 and url encoded signature. Lets call it SG
  6. Now i append the signature we got in step #6 to the querystring in step #4. So the final querystring becomes 
     *SAMLRequest=AR&RelayState=RS&SigAlg=SA&Signature=SG*

All this works fine but the signature validation is failing !

Here's my code which is similar to the code found here https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/v0.21.2/Kentor.AuthServices/WebSSO/Saml2RedirectBinding.cs#L53-L68

```
protected void btnSendAuthRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string authRequest = txtInput.Text;
        //authRequest = authRequest.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
        authRequest = DeflateBase64UrlEncode(authRequest);

        string spPrivateKey= txtKey.Text;
        string relayState = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://example.com/pages/home.aspx");

        string qs = "SAMLRequest=" + authRequest + "&RelayState=" + relayState;
        qs = AddSignature(qs, spPrivateKey);

        txtOutput.Text = qs;
    }

public string AddSignature(string queryString, string PrivateKeyNoHeaders)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider tmpRsa = RSAKeyTests.RSAKeyUtils.DecodePrivateKeyInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(PrivateKeyNoHeaders));

        string signingAlgorithmUrl = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

        queryString += "&SigAlg=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signingAlgorithmUrl);

        var signatureDescription = (SignatureDescription)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(signingAlgorithmUrl);
        HashAlgorithm hashAlg = signatureDescription.CreateDigest();
        hashAlg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString));

AsymmetricSignatureFormatter asymmetricSignatureFormatter =
            signatureDescription.CreateFormatter(
                ((RSACryptoServiceProvider)tmpRsa));
        //.GetSha256EnabledRSACryptoServiceProvider()); 
        // Is the signature failing because of above ? 

        byte[] signatureValue = asymmetricSignatureFormatter.CreateSignature(hashAlg);
        queryString += "&Signature=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(signatureValue));

        return queryString;
    }

private string DeflateBase64UrlEncode(string input)
    {
        var inputs = string.Format(input, Guid.NewGuid());
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputs);
        using (var output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zip = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                zip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray());
            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`CryptoConfig.createFromName(...)` [doesn't know](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig?view=netframework-4.8) about `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1` as the digest+signing algorithm. If  `CryptoConfig.createFromName()` is not returning null, whatever algorithm is registered for `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1` might not be RSA-SHA1. Here's an explicit implementation of `SignatureDescription` with RSA and SHA1:

```
public class RSASHA1SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription {

        public RSASHA1SignatureDescription() {
            KeyAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSA";
            DigestAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng";
            FormatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter";
            DeformatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter";
            _hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";
        }

        public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key) {
            AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter item = (AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(DeformatterAlgorithm);
            item.setKey(key);
            item.SetHashAlgorithm(_hashAlgorithm);
            return item;
        }

        public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key) {
            AsymmetricSignatureFormatter item = (AsymmetricSignatureFormatter) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(FormatterAlgorithm);
            item.setKey(key);
            item.SetHashAlgorithm(_hashAlgorithm);
            return item;
        }

        private string _hashAlgorithm;
    }
```

The other possibility is that however you're validating the signature doesn't want rsa-sha1 (many identity providers prohibit rsa-sha1 via configuration) or the validation is incorrect. Try registering with a real IdP such as Okta or Salesforce and validate there.

Comment: I use (https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php) for validating my requests and that is what is giving the errors that SAML Request is Invalid.

Comment: Try it with a real IdP

Comment: I use (https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php) for validating my requests and that is what is giving the errors that SAML Request is Invalid.If i use other tools of the same site to sign my saml and then validate in the above url, i dont get the error. 
I tried your method but it didn't work. It gives a compile time error that "'RSAPKCS1SHA1SignatureDescription' is inaccessible due to its protection level" 

I also did this:
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(SHA1CryptoServiceProvider), "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"); 
Gave a runtime typecasting error!

Comment: @SuhailWani See update. If that doesn't help, perhaps someone else might have a better answer for you.

Comment: It didn't help. The signature it generated is the same as was being generated before. And the signature the online tools generate is different. 
Also the tool i am using samltool.com is a standard tool and developed by i think onelogin group. So it is kinda legit.