# Unknown crypto algorithm 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1' with Sustainsys.Saml2

Tags: identityserver4, sustainsys-saml2

As a service provider, when trying to connect to a IDP using a SAML2 connection, using IdentityServer4 and Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 package, i keep running into a runtime exception and no real clue if this is a bug or how to tackle it otherwise.
As far as i know this is a perfectly valid crypto algorithm and this is accepted as valid input when retrieving the Metadata for the IDP's URL. Not sure why it keeps telling me it isn't. The Metadata of the client cannot be changed and

I did successfully connect to the mocked https://stupidp.sustainsys.com, using

```
OutboundSigningAlgorithm = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
```

(but not sure if that is a valid comparison).

SAML Metadata file signature section:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl">
      <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/> 
      <ds:DigestValue>...</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>...
```

(for a full file check https://hub-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2)

and a basic configuration

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddSaml2("...", "...", options =>
     { options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
       options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme;
       options.SPOptions.ModulePath = "/Saml2";
       options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("http://localhost:51827");   
       options.SPOptions.MetadataCacheDuration = new XsdDuration(hours: 1);
       options.SPOptions.OutboundSigningAlgorithm = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
       options.SPOptions.MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
       options.IdentityProviders.Add(
         new IdentityProvider(
           new EntityId("..."), options.SPOptions)  
             {
               LoadMetadata = true,                                                       
               MetadataLocation = "..."                          
             });

       options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("....pfx")); 
       options.SPOptions.Organization = organisation;
       options.SPOptions.Contacts.Add(contact);
     });
```

This all results in the following stack trace when clicking the button to connect to this IDP.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unknown crypto algorithm 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Internal.CryptographyExtensions.CreateAlgorithmFromName(String name, Object[] args)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2RedirectBinding.AddSignature(String queryString, ISaml2Message message)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2RedirectBinding.Bind(ISaml2Message message, ILoggerAdapter logger)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.SignInCommand.InitiateLoginToIdp(IOptions options, IDictionary`2 relayData, Saml2Urls urls, IdentityProvider idp, Uri returnUrl)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.SignInCommand.Run(EntityId idpEntityId, String returnPath, HttpRequestData request, IOptions options, IDictionary`2 relayData)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
```

What am i doing wrong or is this not correctly supported ?

Why does it work when connecting to the stubbed IDP ?

Is this missing from `CryptographyExtensions.s_extraAlgorithms` (see open source code) as it only shows 3 of the RSA types listed, where other lists in the code usually name the SHA1 as a fourth?

Answer (score 1):

With the tip of @identigral found that just adding the crypto algorithm again does the trick:

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA1SignatureDescription), SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url);
```

with

```
public class RSAPKCS1SHA1SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
{
        private readonly string _hashAlgorithm;

        public RSAPKCS1SHA1SignatureDescription()
        {
            KeyAlgorithm = typeof(RSACryptoServiceProvider).FullName;
            DigestAlgorithm = typeof(SHA1Managed).FullName;                
            FormatterAlgorithm = typeof(RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter).FullName;
            DeformatterAlgorithm = typeof(RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter).FullName;
            _hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";
        }

        public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            }

            var deformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(key);
            deformatter.SetHashAlgorithm(_hashAlgorithm);
            return deformatter;
        }

        public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            }

            var formatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(key);
            formatter.SetHashAlgorithm(_hashAlgorithm);
            return formatter;
        }     
}
```

Although considered an unsafe protocol, these were given requirements, not my choice. Maybe a future addition to `Sustainsys.Saml2` package is to add this protocol to the list of not recognized protocols in `s_extraAlgorithms` and safe a trivial implementation. But for this one hickup a good package that does the trick just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Even if you set an OutboundSigningAlgorithm, the outbound request to the StubIdp is not signed by default. Signing is enabled if the metadata of the Idp requests it (the StubIdp doesn't) or if AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior is set to Always. If you change it to always, you'll probably get the error even with the StubIdp.
2. The SHA1 algorithm is being phased out, as weaknesses have been discovered in it. My guess is that on your system CryptoConfig.CreateFromName doesn't know of the `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1` name.

But I wouldn't spend time getting SHA1 to work. I would switch to SHA256 instead as that is considered secure.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the stub vs real idp. The real idp is even aware of issues with rsa-sha1 but will for now still requires it (government, slow to change if at all). Saying that, CryptoConfig.CreateFromName also does not recognize http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 but you covered this with an ```s_extraAlgorithms``` dictionary and implementation. Any chance to add it or know a way for me to add it. Stuck now because of this with an otherwise very nicely working framework.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57535442/signature-validation-for-a-saml-authn-request-via-get-method-fails has an example of CryptoConfig implementation with `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1`